# Replacing NaT with specific timestamp in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe between 08:00 and 09:00 time interval daily where I compute duration per each id. I want to replace the NaT on the end column with the upper timestamp of the time interval, in this case it is 09:00, but it can change based on the desired time interval e.g., 09:00 - 12:00 will use 12:00 as the upper time interval.

```
id,date,value
1,2012-01-01 08:09:00,1
1,2012-01-01 08:09:05,1
2,2012-01-01 08:09:15,1
2,2012-01-01 08:09:20,1
1,2012-01-01 08:09:23,1
1,2012-01-01 08:09:30,1
2,2012-01-01 08:09:35,1
2,2012-01-01 08:09:40,1
3,2012-01-01 08:09:47,1
3,2012-01-01 08:09:50,1
1,2012-01-01 08:09:55,1
1,2012-01-01 08:10:05,1
2,2012-01-01 08:10:10,1
2,2012-01-01 08:11:15,1
3,2012-01-01 08:11:20,1
3,2012-01-01 08:11:25,1
3,2012-01-01 08:11:30,1
1,2012-01-01 08:11:35,1
1,2012-01-01 08:11:40,1
1,2012-01-01 08:11:45,1
1,2012-01-01 08:11:50,1
3,2012-01-01 08:11:55,1
3,2012-01-01 08:11:55,1
3,2012-01-01 08:12:10,1
3,2012-01-01 08:12:20,1
3,2012-01-01 08:12:30,1
3,2012-01-01 08:12:45,1
3,2012-01-01 08:12:55,1
3,2012-01-01 08:13:00,1
2,2012-01-01 08:13:15,1
```

I have tried the below but my output still retains the NaT:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('df.csv')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
diff_ids = df['id'] != df['id'].shift(1)
df = df[diff_ids].copy()
df['start'] = df['date']
df['end'] = df['date'].shift(-1)
upper_timestamp = df['end'].dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('09:00:00')
df['end'] = df['end'].fillna(upper_timestamp)
df['duration'] = df['end'] - df['start']
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
id,date,value,start,end,duration
1,2012-01-01 08:09:00,1,2012-01-01 08:09:00,2012-01-01 08:09:15,00:00:15
2,2012-01-01 08:09:15,1,2012-01-01 08:09:15,2012-01-01 08:09:23,00:00:08
1,2012-01-01 08:09:23,1,2012-01-01 08:09:23,2012-01-01 08:09:35,00:00:12
2,2012-01-01 08:09:35,1,2012-01-01 08:09:35,2012-01-01 08:09:47,00:00:12
3,2012-01-01 08:09:47,1,2012-01-01 08:09:47,2012-01-01 08:09:55,00:00:08
1,2012-01-01 08:09:55,1,2012-01-01 08:09:55,2012-01-01 08:10:10,00:00:15
2,2012-01-01 08:10:10,1,2012-01-01 08:10:10,2012-01-01 08:11:20,00:01:10
3,2012-01-01 08:11:20,1,2012-01-01 08:11:20,2012-01-01 08:11:35,00:00:15
1,2012-01-01 08:11:35,1,2012-01-01 08:11:35,2012-01-01 08:11:55,00:00:20
3,2012-01-01 08:11:55,1,2012-01-01 08:11:55,2012-01-01 08:13:15,00:01:20
2,2012-01-01 08:13:15,1,2012-01-01 08:13:15,NaT,NaT
```

**Desired output**

```
id,date,value,start,end,duration
1,2012-01-01 08:09:00,1,2012-01-01 08:09:00,2012-01-01 08:09:15,00:00:15
2,2012-01-01 08:09:15,1,2012-01-01 08:09:15,2012-01-01 08:09:23,00:00:08
1,2012-01-01 08:09:23,1,2012-01-01 08:09:23,2012-01-01 08:09:35,00:00:12
2,2012-01-01 08:09:35,1,2012-01-01 08:09:35,2012-01-01 08:09:47,00:00:12
3,2012-01-01 08:09:47,1,2012-01-01 08:09:47,2012-01-01 08:09:55,00:00:08
1,2012-01-01 08:09:55,1,2012-01-01 08:09:55,2012-01-01 08:10:10,00:00:15
2,2012-01-01 08:10:10,1,2012-01-01 08:10:10,2012-01-01 08:11:20,00:01:10
3,2012-01-01 08:11:20,1,2012-01-01 08:11:20,2012-01-01 08:11:35,00:00:15
1,2012-01-01 08:11:35,1,2012-01-01 08:11:35,2012-01-01 08:11:55,00:00:20
3,2012-01-01 08:11:55,1,2012-01-01 08:11:55,2012-01-01 08:13:15,00:01:20
2,2012-01-01 08:13:15,1,2012-01-01 08:13:15,2012-01-01 09:00:00,00:46:45
```

How can I fix my problem and also choose the upper timestamp automatically without hard coding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can use the upper timestamp from startdate using `series.dt.ceil` and using frequency as hour:

```
df['end'] = df['end'].fillna(df['start'].dt.ceil('H'))
```

Which gives:

```
    id                date  value               start                 end  \
0    1 2012-01-01 08:09:00      1 2012-01-01 08:09:00 2012-01-01 08:09:15   
2    2 2012-01-01 08:09:15      1 2012-01-01 08:09:15 2012-01-01 08:09:23   
4    1 2012-01-01 08:09:23      1 2012-01-01 08:09:23 2012-01-01 08:09:35   
6    2 2012-01-01 08:09:35      1 2012-01-01 08:09:35 2012-01-01 08:09:47   
8    3 2012-01-01 08:09:47      1 2012-01-01 08:09:47 2012-01-01 08:09:55   
10   1 2012-01-01 08:09:55      1 2012-01-01 08:09:55 2012-01-01 08:10:10   
12   2 2012-01-01 08:10:10      1 2012-01-01 08:10:10 2012-01-01 08:11:20   
14   3 2012-01-01 08:11:20      1 2012-01-01 08:11:20 2012-01-01 08:11:35   
17   1 2012-01-01 08:11:35      1 2012-01-01 08:11:35 2012-01-01 08:11:55   
21   3 2012-01-01 08:11:55      1 2012-01-01 08:11:55 2012-01-01 08:13:15   
29   2 2012-01-01 08:13:15      1 2012-01-01 08:13:15 2012-01-01 09:00:00   

          duration  
0  0 days 00:00:15  
2  0 days 00:00:08  
4  0 days 00:00:12  
6  0 days 00:00:12  
8  0 days 00:00:08  
10 0 days 00:00:15  
12 0 days 00:01:10  
14 0 days 00:00:15  
17 0 days 00:00:20  
21 0 days 00:01:20  
29 0 days 00:46:45
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...this fixes my problem.